# css - add padding to the horizontal menu without changing width of the border

Tags: css, text, alignment

I have http://jsfiddle.net/dfo44q7f/3/

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="/">Menu1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Menu2/">Menu2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Menu3/">Menu3</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

How do i:

- i'd like to keep the line underneath of the menu as wide as the text
- but also add padding to the left and right of the li

Comment: Wrap your ul.nav in another div and you'll have more control

Comment: You can use the `margin` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for margin..

```
.nav li{
    display:inline;
    border-bottom: 1px solid currentColor;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    margin-left:50px; 
}
```

Comment: `margin: 0 25px;` would apply equal margins on the left and right and keep the menu centered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like that ?

http://jsfiddle.net/dfo44q7f/5/

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.nav {
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width : 200px;
    margin : auto;
    overflow : hidden;
}
.nav li {
    display:block;
    float : left;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    width : 33.33%;
}
.nav a {
    display:inline;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999;
    border-bottom: 1px solid currentColor;
    padding-bottom : 5px;
}
.nav a:hover {
    color: #0088cc;
}
```

If this is what you want I'll **explain** what I changed in **your code,**

Comment: not exactly.  1-the nav should be the width of the entire page.  2-the underline underneath the "menu" text should align to the border underneath.